# Hiding scrollbar in non fixed divs

Tags: html, css

I've run into trouble while trying to hide scrollbars from certain divs.
I found some solutions on the forum but they never really match my case so I'm still struggling with the problem.
My problem: I'm trying to hide scrollbars in a div that is nested inside another div that has non fixed size. (they are set to 100% of the body).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="events">
    <div id="event-list"></div>
    <div id="event-details"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#events {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#event-list {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

#event-details {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

[Codepen available here](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/pvMQzw)

I would like #event-list and #event-details to have no scrollbar but still be scrollable. If you have any idea (css? js? jquery?), I'll take it!
Thanks in advance,
alex

Comment: @MikeK thanks for your reply, I managed to fix my issue thanks to this post. I updated the Codepen above if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested div with the outer div's width set to 100% with `overflow:hidden` and the inner div set to a width of 105% (you can fine tune this value) and overflow set to `overflow:scroll`

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q/669/)

Comment: I had found this solution but wasn't a big fan of the 105%. I managed to fix the issue, checkout the Codepen above if you're interested. Thanks for your help.